# How to synchronize/lock correctly when using CountDownLatch

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, blocking

It boils down to one thread submitting job via some service. Job is executed in some TPExecutor. Afterwards this service checks for results and throw exception in original thread under certain conditions (job exceeds maximum number of retries, etc.). Code snippet below roughly illustrate this scenario in legacy code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class IncorrectLockingExample {

private static class Request {

    private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    private Throwable throwable;

    public void await() {
        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException ignoredForDemoPurposes) {
        }
    }

    public void countDown() {
        latch.countDown();
    }

    public Throwable getThrowable() {
        return throwable;
    }

    public void setThrowable(Throwable throwable) {
        this.throwable = throwable;
    }

}

private static final Request wrapper = new Request();

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    final Thread blockedThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            wrapper.await();
            synchronized (wrapper) {
                if (wrapper.getThrowable() != null)
                    throw new RuntimeException(wrapper.getThrowable());
            }
        }
    };

    final Thread workingThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            wrapper.setThrowable(new RuntimeException());
            wrapper.countDown();

        }
    };

    blockedThread.start();
    workingThread.start();

    blockedThread.join();
    workingThread.join();
}
```

}

Sometimes, (not reproducible on my box, but happens on 16 core server box) exception isn't getting reported to original thread. I think this is because happens-before is not forced(eg.  'countDown' happens before 'setThrowable') and program continues to work(but should fail). 
I would appreciate any help about how to resolve this case. 
Constraints are: release in a week, minimum impact on existing codebase is needed.

Comment: 250 KLOC project here fully multi-threaded, working on 16-cores etc.  We use "high-level" multi-threaded facilities like *CountDownLatch* a **lot**.  The number of times we use low level things like *Object*'s *wait()* method and *Thread*'s *join()* method?  **ZERO**.  In my opinion there are nowadays enough high-level concurrency facility in the default API that you do not need to reinvent any broken wheel based on Java idiosynchrasies.  +1 to Peter Lawrey's answer.

Comment: @Webinator: OP *is* using the "high-level" `CountDownLatch` facility for one of its designed purposes here.

Comment: are you sure that the code above is not behaving as expected? I see no reason for it not to after you made the correction.

Comment: I didn't realise wait() was a broken wheel/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code above (as now updated) should work as you expected without the use of further synchronisation mechanisms. The memory barrier and its corresponding *'happens-before'* relationship is enforced by the use of the `CountDownLatch` `await()` and `countdown()` methods.

From the [API docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility):

> *Actions prior to "releasing" synchronizer methods such as Lock.unlock, Semaphore.release, and CountDownLatch.countDown happen-before actions subsequent to a successful "acquiring" method such as Lock.lock, Semaphore.acquire, Condition.await, and CountDownLatch.await on the same synchronizer object in another thread.*

If you are dealing with concurrency on a regular basis get yourself a copy of ['Java Concurrency in Practice'](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601), it's the Java concurrency bible and will be well worth its weight on your bookshelf :-).

Comment: CountDownLatch await/countDown guarantees happen-before(thanks for pointing to API docs, I didn't know this fact). However happen-before itself doesn't guarantee visibility of changes made before CountDownLatch.countDown. Therefore the only solutions would be to have throwable as volatile, or do it update in 'synchronized (throwable) {...}' block. Does that make sence

Comment: @Petro Semeniuk: no, the happens-before relationship guarantees visibility of all previous writes across the memory barrier, i.e. whatever you do in `workingThread` before `countDown()` will be visible in `blockedThread` after the corresponding `await()` has returned. Using `synchronized` just for the purpose of creating a memory barrier is considered bad (this is what `volatile` is for) and anyway `volatile` is not needed here as your thread synchronisation using the `CountDownLatch` methods already create the required memory barrier and happens-before relationship.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you need

```
private volatile Throwable throwable
```

Have you tried using an ExecutorService as it is built in and does this for you. The following prints

```
future1 := result
future2  threw java.lang.IllegalStateException
future3  timed out
```

The code is

```
public static void main(String... args)  {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<String> future1 = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        public String call() throws Exception {
            return "result";
        }
    });

    Future<String> future2 = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        public String call() throws Exception {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    });

    Future<String> future3 = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        public String call() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            throw new AssertionError();
        }
    });

    printResult("future1", future1);
    printResult("future2", future2);
    printResult("future3", future3);
    executor.shutdown();
}

private static void printResult(String description, Future<String> future) {
    try {
        System.out.println(description+" := "+future.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(description+"  interrupted");
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        System.out.println(description+"  threw "+e.getCause());
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        System.out.println(description+"  timed out");
    }
}
```

In the code for FutureTask, there is a comment.

```
/**
 * The thread running task. When nulled after set/cancel, this
 * indicates that the results are accessible.  Must be
 * volatile, to ensure visibility upon completion.
 */
```

If you are not going to re-use the code in the JDK, it can still be worth reading it so you can pick up on any tricks they use.

Comment: +1 for `ExecutorService` suggestion, but `volatile` keyword will not do anything useful here.

Comment: Thanks for providing example with FutureTask. Looks like that what we have to upgrade to in future (instead of using composite of  CountDownLatch and throwable). Unfortunately I have slightly different situation when happen-before guaranteed. In case of FutureTask 'volatile' runner is needed because happen-before isn't guaranteed by callable (innerRunAndReset method).