# How to make writes to array visible to other Threads

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, concurrency

I have an input array of basic type int, I would like to process this array using multiple threads and store the results in an output array of same type and size. Is the following code correct in terms of memory visibility?

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ArraySynchronization2
{
    final int width = 100;
    final int height = 100;

    final int[][] img = new int[width][height];
    volatile int[][] avg = new int[width][height];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
    {
        new ArraySynchronization2().doJob();;
    }

    private void doJob() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
    {
        final int threadNo = 8;
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadNo);

        final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(width - 2);

        for (int x = 1; x < width - 1; x++)
        {
            final int col = x;
            pool.execute(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                    {
                        avg[col][y] = (img[col - 1][y] + img[col][y] + img[col + 1][y]) / 3;
                    }
                    // how can I make the writes to the data in avg[][] visible to other threads? is this ok?
                    avg = avg;
                    countDownLatch.countDown();
                };
            });
        }

        try
        {
            // Does this make any memory visibility guarantees?
            countDownLatch.await();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // can I read avg here, will the results be correct?
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                System.out.println(avg[x][y]);
            }
        }

        pool.shutdown();
        pool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);

        // now I know tasks are completed and results synchronized (after thread death), but what if I plan to reuse the pool?
    }
}
```

I do not want to synchronize on CountDownLatch. I would like to know how to make the writes to the output array visible to other threads. Let imagine that I have an array (eg. image) that I would like to process, I could do this in multiple separate tasks that process chunks of the input array into the output array, there are no inter-dependencies between the writes to the output. After all computations complete, I would like to have all the results in the output array ready to read. How could I achieve such behaviour? I know that it is achievable by using submit and Future.get() instead of execute, I'd like to know how to properly implement such low-level mechanism? Please also refer to the questions raised in comments near the code.

Comment: Read the documentation for `CountDownLatch.await();`, it should tell you about any guarantees.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to synchronize/lock correctly when using CountDownLatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352827/how-to-synchronize-lock-correctly-when-using-countdownlatch)

Comment: Read the javadoc for `CountdownLatch`, and search for the paragraph that begins with, "Memory consistency effects."

Comment: True, but only if the latch count reflects the number of jobs, which wasn't the case before the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, just wondering if you actually need a latch. The array itself is a reserved block in memory, with every cell being a dedicated memory address. (btw. marking it volatile does only mark the *reference* to the array as volatile, not the cells of the array, see [here](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.ch/2009/06/volatile-arrays-in-java.html)). So you need to coordinate access to the cells only if multiple threads write-access the same cell.

Question is, are you actually doing this? Or the aim should be: avoid coordinating access if possible, because it comes at a cost.

In your algorithm, you operate on rows, so why not parallelize on rows, so that each thread only reads & calculates values of a row-segement of the entire array and ignore the other rows?

i.e.

- thread-0 -> rows 0, 8, 15, ...
- thread-1 -> rows 1, 9, 16, ...
- ...

basically this (haven't tested):

```
for (int n = 0; n < threadNo; n++)  { //each n relates to a thread
    pool.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (int row = n; row < height; row += threadNo) { //proceed to the next row for the thread
                for (int col = 1; col < width-1; col++) {
                    avg[col][row] = (img[col - 1][row] + img[col][row] + img[col + 1][row]) / 3;
                   }
                }
            };
        });
    }
```

So they can operate on the entire array without having to synchronize at all. An by putting the loop to print out the result after shutting down the pool will ensure all calculate-threads have finished, and the only thread that has to wait is the main thread.

An alternative to this approach is to create an avg-array of size `100/ThreadNo` for each thread so that each thread write-operate on it's on array and you merge the arrays afterwards with `System.arraycopy()` into one array.

If you intend to reuse the pool, you should use `submit` instead of execute and call `get()` on the [Futures](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) you get from submit.

```
Set<Future> futures = new HashSet<>();
for(int n = 0; ...) {
   futures.add(pool.submit(new Runnable() {...}));
}

for(Future f : futures) {
  f.get(); //blocks until the task is completed
}
```

In case you want to read intermediate states of the array you can either read it directly, if inconsistent data on single cells is acceptable, or use [AtomicIntegerArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html), as Nicolas Filotto suggested.

-- EDIT --

After the edit for using the width for the latch instead of the original thread number and all the discussion I'd like to add a few words.

As @jameslarge pointed out, it's about how to establish a "happens-before" relationship, or how to guarantee, that operation A (i.e. a write) happens before operation B (i.e. a read). Therefore access between two threads needs to be coordinated. There are several options

- volatile keyword - doesn't work on arrays as it marks only the *reference* and not the values as being volatile
- synchronization - pessimistic locking (`synchronized` modifier or statement)
- CAS - optimistic locking, used by quite a few concurrent implementations

However every syncpoint (pessimistic or optimistic) establishes a happens-before relationship. Which one you choose, depends on your requirement.

What you like to achieve is a coordination between the read operation of the main thread and the write operations of the worker threads. How do you implement, is up to you and your requirements. The CountDownLatch counting down the total number of jobs is one way (btw., the latch uses a state property which is a `volatile int`). A [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) may also be a construct worth to consider, especially if you'd like to read consistent intermediate states. Or a future.get(), or... 
All boils down to the worker thread having to signal they're done writingso the reader thread can start reading.

However be aware of using sleep instead of synchronization. Sleep does not establish a happens before relationship, and using sleep for synchronization is a typical concurrency bug pattern. I.e. in the worst case, sleep is executed before any of the work has been done.

Comment: It is already parallelized, that it ignores what other threads do

Comment: I would like to know how low-level mechanisms that are used in Future.get() or other synchronization techniques works - so I'd like to know how to write it myself using basic java synchronization.

Comment: your code parallelizes on column and each thread writes in each row - this could end up messy. The latch won't help you there as it'll synchronize only the first 8 iterations, after that they're not coordinated anymore. A lot of the concurrent implementations rely on optimistic locking using CAS which uses a dedicated processor instruction, you couldn't implement this with java synchronization and even get close to the same performance.

Comment: Re, "you need to coordinate access to the cells only if ...", the question is not about "coordinating access," the question is about _visibility_.  I.e., If a worker thread stores a value into `avg[i][j]`, when (if ever) will the main thread be able to see that value?  The answer is, the main thread is _never_ guaranteed to see the update unless the two threads do something (e.g., the trick with the `CountdownLatch`) that establishes a _happens before_ relationship between the two threads.

Comment: If thread A calls `latch.countDown()`, and thread B calls `latch.await()` for the same `latch` object, then Java guarantees that everything that happened in thread A before the `countDown()` call also happens before the `await()` call returns in thread B.

Comment: @jameslarge please add your answer, so I could accept it, I suspected this, but you confirmed it, that I just need something to establish happens before (in any way) between those threads to make it visible.

Comment: @james, *visibility* is a coordinated read access, read has to be coordinated with a write to give any guarantees. Without coordination there are no guarantees - neither consistency, nor visibility. Every synchronization mechanism coordinates access to establish a logical order of events before and after the syncpoint. Regardless of being a latch, barrier, join, synchronize or future.get. Visibility is a write-happens-before-read, and its no different to write1-happens-before-write2.

Comment: @GeraldMücke So if I remove the CountDownLatch, and leave only the volatile write "avg = avg" and wait in some way for the threads to finish (sleep 10 sec), it is sufficient to read correct results from the array?

Comment: I'm actually unsure about the `avg=avg` statement, I wouldn't trust it not to be optimized away although being volatile. And sleep() is certainly not good for synchronization as it does not establish a logical sequence of events. Coordination is not about time but about order of events.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to use is rather an [AtomicIntegerArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html) instead of a simple `volatile int array`. Indeed, it is meant to be used in your case to update array element atomically and visible by all threads.